# Rename TwoFactorUserId cookie in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In asp.net core 1.1 you were able to set the TwoFactorUserId cookie name with the following code, but how is it done in v2.0/2.1?

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
{
options.Cookies.TwoFactorUserIdCookie.CookieName = "cookieName";
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: https://forums.asp.net/t/2128896.aspx?Two+factor+cookie+options+in+ASP+Core+2+0

Seems a lot of work just to change the 2FA cookie name, but it's the only solution that I've found. If there's an easier way, please let me know...

If anyone else has this issue, you basically need to replace the default Identity schemas, so you need to replace your services.AddIdentity configuration with:

```
        var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options =>
        {
            //options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
            //options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        }
        );
        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(ApplicationRole), builder.Services);
        builder.AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<ApplicationRole>>();
        builder.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();
        builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Then add Identity schemas:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
          .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, o =>
          {
              o.Cookie.Name = "appCookie";
              o.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
              o.LogoutPath = new PathString("/account/logout");
              o.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/account/accessdenied");
          })
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, o =>
        {
            o.Cookie.Name = "externalCookie";
        })
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme, o =>
        {
            o.Cookie.Name = "2faCookie";
        })
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme, o =>
        {
            o.Cookie.Name = "2faUserIdCookie";
        }); ;
```

Comment: Simple thing made complicated? Seems like a step backward from v1.1

Comment: I know it's been a while, but wondering if you know or still remember how to read the 2fa cookie? I was able to retrieve it in the code, and decrypt it, but wondering if there is a way to read it letting the framework do all the work, kind of like User.Claims for the authentication cookie.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For asp.net core 3.1 you can use the following to configure the cookie without having to replace the whole thing.

For the default Identity cookie they have a helper method:

```
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(c =>
        {
            c.Cookie.Name = ".appCookie";
            c.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
            c.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

for the rest of the cookies you can use the `Configure` extension method:

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme,
            c => { c.Cookie.Name = ".2faCookie"; });
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme,
            c => { c.Cookie.Name = ".2faUserIdCookie"; });
```